# Is there a way to try out a netplan configuration without altering the system?

Tags: boot, networking, netplan

I work on remote servers, and its a painfull process to go into Rescue Mode everytime I screw something up when it comes to network configuraitons.

Are there a way to implement something like:

```
Netplan apply /customscript.yaml
```

That I can use when I troubleshoot network configurations. 
So the server gets its "defaults" if I do a cold reboot.

Comment: Are you trying to restore the default .yaml file and then netplan apply? Can you save the default as default.yaml.bak and then: `sudo mv default.yaml.bak  01-netcfg.yaml  && netplan apply`  ?

Comment: this is an valid option as long as you have local access to the server, not over network. I only have 1 network card, and can only access the server using ssh. So if i mess something up in the netplan, and load it. then i have to boot the server up in recovery mode and do this you just described. What I want is to be able to apply settings in netplan, that are reversed back to a default setup when i reboot the server, incase i mess up.

Comment: What I can try to create a bash script that load on boot, where i use cat to write the defaults to 01-netctf.yaml.

Comment: I'd look into /etc/rc.local.

Comment: One thing I'm working on is "netplan try", so that configuration could be "attempted" live and if you don't answer a prompt, it is automatically reverted to the previous configuration. Would that help in your case?

Comment: @mathieuTrudel-Lapierre Yes, that is exactly what im looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I created a sh script, placed it in /etc/netplan/ and named it backup.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

# -q quiet
# -c nb of pings to perform

ping -q -c5 aa.bb.cc.dd > /dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
        : #do absolutly nothing! server can ping its external IP.
else 
        # restore, working config to netplan.
        cp -f /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml 
        # apply network config.
        netplan apply
fi
```

This script revert the changes I have made, to a working configuration setup that I have stored in 02-netcfg.yaml If i cant ping the server IP. I have masked my server IP address whit aa.bb.cc.dd So you have to replace that whit the IP you want to ping, in order to execute the "else" in the if.

*Then i set this script to run everytime the server restart, as well as enable a Cron job for it that runs every 3 minutes when i work on network configurations.*

Comment: A question, to simplyfy the script even more: Can i add a netplan - c /etc/netplan/02-netcfg.yaml apply or something like that?

Answer (score 9):

There is a new way to do this in Bionic: `netplan try`.

In your case, `netplan try --config-file foo.yaml` should do what you want.

The manpage isn't very helpful as it mostly describes the config file format, but `--help` gives you a pretty good outline of the tool:

```
ubuntu@netplan:~$ netplan try --help
usage: /usr/sbin/netplan try [-h] [--debug] [--config-file CONFIG_FILE]
                             [--timeout TIMEOUT]

Try to apply a new netplan config to running system, with automatic rollback

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --debug               Enable debug messages
  --config-file CONFIG_FILE
                        Apply the config file in argument in addition to
                        current configuration.
  --timeout TIMEOUT     Maximum number of seconds to wait for the user's
                        confirmation
```